JSON Schema behavior of unevaluatedProperties
Within JSON Schema, I am struggling figuring out the behavior of how unevaluatedProperties works with child conditional fields.  I have an example schema that I am attempting to get the validator to come back and say that these three fields should not be present:

level1_ShouldNotBeHere
field5_ShouldNotBeHere
array1_ShouldNotBeHere

{
    "level1_ShouldNotBeHere": "value",
    "level1": {
        "field1": "field1_value1",
        "field2": "field2value",
        "field4": "field3value",
        "field5_ShouldNotBeHere": "value",
        "array_1": [
            {
                "method_array_1": "method_array_1_value1",
                "detail_array_1": "detail_array_1_value",
                "array1_ShouldNotBeHere": "value"
            }
        ]
    }
}

{
    "required": [
        "level1"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "level1": {
            "type": "object",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field1": {
                                "enum": [
                                    "field1_value1"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field3": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "oneOf": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "field3_value1",
                                        "const": "field3_value1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "field3_value2",
                                        "const": "field3_value2"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "field4": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "array_1": {
                                "minItems": 1,
                                "items": {
                                    "required": [
                                        "method_array_1",
                                        "detail_array_1"
                                    ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "method_array_1": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "oneOf": [
                                                {
                                                    "title": "method_array_1_value1",
                                                    "const": "method_array_1_value1"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "title": "method_array_1_value2",
                                                    "const": "method_array_1_value2"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "title": "Method"
                                        },
                                        "detail_array_1": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "title": "Detail"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array",
                                "title": "Array 1 Title"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "title": "field1_value1",
                            "const": "field1_value1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "field1_value2",
                            "const": "field1_value2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "field2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Unit"
}

Ultimately, I am attempting to use a validator (AJV) to return back a list of errors related to unevaluatedProperties, and remove those fields from the resulting json.
In this example, I can get the first two fields to come back, however I cannot figure out where to put the unevaluatedProperties to have the below field come back as an error: array1_ShouldNotBeHere
{
    "required": [
        "level1"
    ],
      "unevaluatedProperties" : false,
    "properties": {
     
        "level1": {
            "type": "object",
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field1": {
                                "enum": [
                                    "field1_value1"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field3": {
                                "type": "string",
                                "oneOf": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "field3_value1",
                                        "const": "field3_value1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "field3_value2",
                                        "const": "field3_value2"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "field4": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "array_1": {
                                "minItems": 1,
                                "items": {
                                    "required": [
                                        "method_array_1",
                                        "detail_array_1"
                                    ],
                                    "properties": {
                                        "method_array_1": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "oneOf": [
                                                {
                                                    "title": "method_array_1_value1",
                                                    "const": "method_array_1_value1"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "title": "method_array_1_value2",
                                                    "const": "method_array_1_value2"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "title": "Method"
                                        },
                                        "detail_array_1": {
                                            "type": "string",
                                            "title": "Detail"
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "type": "object"
                                },
                                "type": "array",
                                "title": "Array 1 Title"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
              "unevaluatedProperties" : false,
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "title": "field1_value1",
                            "const": "field1_value1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "field1_value2",
                            "const": "field1_value2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "field2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "title": "Unit"
}


This should accomplish what you explained.
unevaluatedProperties should be set at each object schema location where you expect no other properties to be defined.
In your example, the root schema, the level1 schema and the array_1 items schema.
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "title": "Unit",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "level1"
    ],
    "unevaluatedProperties": false,
    "properties": {
        "level1": {
            "allOf": [
                {
                    "if": {
                        "properties": {
                            "field1": {
                                "const": "field1_value1"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "type": "object",
                        "properties": {
                            "field3": {
                                "oneOf": [
                                    {
                                        "title": "field3_value1",
                                        "const": "field3_value1"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "title": "field3_value2",
                                        "const": "field3_value2"
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            "field4": {
                                "type": "string"
                            },
                            "array_1": {
                                "title": "Array 1 Title",
                                "type": "array",
                                "minItems": 1,
                                "items": {
                                    "required": [
                                        "method_array_1",
                                        "detail_array_1"
                                    ],
                                    "type": "object",
                                    "unevaluatedProperties": false,
                                    "properties": {
                                        "method_array_1": {
                                            "oneOf": [
                                                {
                                                    "title": "method_array_1_value1",
                                                    "const": "method_array_1_value1"
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "title": "method_array_1_value2",
                                                    "const": "method_array_1_value2"
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "title": "Method"
                                        },
                                        "detail_array_1": {
                                            "title": "Detail",
                                            "type": "string"
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "type": "object",
            "unevaluatedProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "field1": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {
                            "title": "field1_value1",
                            "const": "field1_value1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title": "field1_value2",
                            "const": "field1_value2"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "field2": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


EDIT:
jsonschemavalidator is not fully compliant with draft 2020-12 so the output may vary from other implementations.
using https://json-everything.net/json-schema
You can see on line 44 of the evaluation results that field4 is valid.
{
  "valid": true,
  "evaluationPath": "/properties/level1/allOf/0/then/properties/field4",
  "schemaLocation": "https://json-everything.net/5c1ef24063#/properties/level1/allOf/0/then/properties/field4",
  "instanceLocation": "/level1/field4"
}


i've found two other online validators which provide a much better experience than NewtonSoft and are updated to the latest specification.   https://json-schema.hyperjump.io  https://json-everything.net/json-schema/

When running that against the json, it shows field4 as being unevaluated (i.e. should not be there): https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/s/mPwI1Ols

updated the answer

Although it has field4 as valid in your results, it also includes:
{
"valid": false,
"evaluationPath": "/properties/level1/unevaluatedProperties",
"schemaLocation": "https://json-everything.net/e52bc90399#/properties/level1/unevaluatedProperties",
"instanceLocation": "/level1/field4/field4",
"errors": {
"": "All values fail against the false schema"
}

right, it would fail until the validation of the then statement which defines the schema for field4, which validates as true.
